# ¿Cómo configurar las etiquetas de cada área en un diagrama de venn?

Tags: r

Quería saber como poder hacer un diagrama de Venn que esté relleno con el nombre de las especies vegetales de mi análisis y no con el número de las mismas.

Hasta ahora solo he conseguido hacer dicha función con un script que me permite hacer el diagrama solo con 3 agrupamientos y no con cuatro como quiero.

El script que he seguido ha sido este:

```
 library(VennDiagram)

 BM1 <- c('Cistaceae', 'Oleaceae','Fagaceae','Rhamnaceae','Asteraceae','Asteraceae')
 BM2 <- c('Boraginaceae','Poaceae','Poaceae')
 BM3 <-  c('Poaceae','Asteraceae','Chenopodiaceae','Asteraceae','Poaceae','Solanaceae','Solanaceae','Asteraceae','Rubiaceae')
 BM4<- c('Amaranthaceae','Chenopodiaceae','Convolvulaceae','Convolvulaceae','Cucurbitaceae','Cucurbitaceae','Cucurbitaceae','Cucurbitaceae','Boraginaceae','Boraginaceae','Solanaceae')

 v2 <- venn.diagram(list(Oak=BM1, Wasteland=BM2,Edge=BM3, Crop=BM4),
               fill = c("red", "blue","green","purple"),
               alpha = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0.5), cat.cex = 1.5, cex=1.5,
               filename=NULL)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v2)


 v2[[7]]$label  <- paste(setdiff(BM1,union(BM2,BM3)),collapse = "")
 inters <- intersect(BM1,intersect(BM2,BM3))
 v2[[8]]$label <- paste(setdiff(intersect(BM1,BM2), inters),collapse = "")
 v2[[9]]$label <- paste(setdiff(BM2,union(BM1,BM3)),collapse = "")
 v2[[10]]$label <- paste(setdiff(intersect(BM1,BM3), inters),collapse = "")
 v2[[11]]$label <- paste(ww[[1,5]], collapse = "")
 v2[[12]]$label <- paste(setdiff(intersect(BM3,BM2), inters),collapse = "")
 v2[[13]]$label <- paste(setdiff(BM3,union(BM1,BM2)),collapse = "")


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v2)
```

¿Qué debería de cambiar?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Importante**: Esta solución parece funcionar correctamente para los conjuntos indicados, incluso para con un gráfico de 5 conjuntos, sin embargo para graficos de 3 o 2 conjuntos, posiblemente por que en estos el orden de las etiquetas sea distintno, la solución no funciona de forma adecuada.

---

Hay una forma, si bien trabajosa, al menos sí, dinámica. En primer lugar, vamos a necesitar los conjuntos en una lista, y configurar un tamaño de letra para las etiquetas un numero más pequeño que en tu ejemplo:

```
library(VennDiagram)

BM1 <- c('Cistaceae', 'Oleaceae','Fagaceae','Rhamnaceae','Asteraceae','Asteraceae')
BM2 <- c('Boraginaceae','Poaceae','Poaceae')
BM3 <- c('Poaceae','Asteraceae','Chenopodiaceae','Asteraceae','Poaceae','Solanaceae','Solanaceae','Asteraceae','Rubiaceae')
BM4<- c('Amaranthaceae','Chenopodiaceae','Convolvulaceae','Convolvulaceae','Cucurbitaceae','Cucurbitaceae','Cucurbitaceae','Cucurbitaceae','Boraginaceae','Boraginaceae','Solanaceae')

lista_conjuntos <- list(Oak=BM1, Wasteland=BM2,Edge=BM3, Crop=BM4)

v2 <- venn.diagram(lista_conjuntos,
                   fill = c("red", "blue","green","purple"),
                   alpha = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0.5), cat.cex = 1.5, cex=.8,
                   filename=NULL)
```

Ahora, teniendo `lista_conjuntos`, vamos a construir las etiquetas de cada área de intersección, para esto podemos usar [`calculate.overlap()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VennDiagram/versions/1.6.20/topics/calculate.overlap) del propio paquete `VennDiagram`:

```
labels <- lapply(calculate.overlap(lista_conjuntos), function(x) {paste(unique(x), collapse='\n')})

 tail(labels, 3)
$`a14`
[1] ""

$a1
[1] "Rubiaceae"

$a3
[1] "Amaranthaceae\nConvolvulaceae\nCucurbitaceae"
```

Lo que obtenemos es una lista con los nombres de los elementos de cada intersección, dónde además en el nombre del elemento (`a1..an`) tenemos un índice que no permitira luego acceder a los elementos del diagrama de venn, es decir el objeto `v2`. Este objeto es un `Grob List`, una lista de objetos gráficos, los primeros objetos de la lista son los polígonos que se dibujan y los siguientes son las etiquetas (que por defecto tienen las cantidad de elementos de cada área). Estos elementos son del tipo `text`, y nos interesará ubicar el primero de estos:

```
min(which(unlist(lapply(v2, function(x) {class(x)[[1]]}=="text"))))
[1] 9
```

El elemento 9 será la intersección `a1`, el 10 es `a2`y así. Obviamente esto variará en función a la cantidad de conjuntos. Entonces podremos configurar la etiqueta deseada y dibujar ahora sí el diagrama:

```
for (x in names(labels)) {
    v2[[ start + as.integer(gsub("a", "",x)) ]]$label = labels[[x]]
}

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v2)
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!